# SFMC SQL, for [Where NOT IN] on multiple columns

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

I have a simple query where I want to see how many records were not added in DE. But with below query I am getting error "Errors: An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected"

```
select 
q.email_address, q.uuid
from usca_restaurant_contact_v3 q
where (q.email_address, q.uuid) not in 
(select p.email_address, p.uuid from usca_restaurant_contact_v3_chkng_pk p)
```

Any other way to do this? I am trying to see how many records from usca_restaurant_contact_v3 were not added into usca_restaurant_contact_v3_chkng_pk?

Answer (score 1):

Just from a quick glance, I would use a left join instead for this. See below:

```
select 
q.email_address, q.uuid
from usca_restaurant_contact_v3 q
left join (
    select p.email_address, p.uuid
    from usca_restaurant_contact_v3_chkng_pk p
) b
ON q.email_address = b.email_address AND q.uuid = b.uuid
WHERE b.email_address IS NULL
AND b.uuid IS NULL
```

By using the above `WHERE` statement it will only pull records from `q` that do not exist in `p`.

Comment: I tried but getting an error.. 
Errors: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'

Comment: sorry forgot the ON statement, will edit now

Comment: didn't work. Showing 0 record.

Comment: Have you verified that there are records where both email and uuid do not exist in q but do exist in p? If one exists, but not the other, it will not be displayed. For instance in q you have a record with `a@a.com | 909` and in p you have `b@a.com | 909` - these would not show up in your target as 909 is shared, so it is not null for both.

Comment: They do exist in Q but not in P. And that's what I want to check that how many records from P did not load into Q.

Comment: The answer would appear to be 0 then. I have used the above in a sample with same parameters and it returned expected results.

Comment: ok in this case how do I resolve this. I want to see all the records those were not uploaded in P from Q. ???

Comment: You could try doing an 'OR' to get records where email_address or uuid is null in p (meaning that one of those is null, but the other does not need to be.). This should give you some records to help with troubleshooting for you to work on.

Comment: Using "or" is still showing me 0 records. I have 1,856,259 records in Q and 1,371,592 records uploaded in P.

Answer (score 1):

The solution provided by Gortonington should work.

Alternatively, please try

```
SELECT 
q.email_address, q.uuid
FROM usca_restaurant_contact_v3 q
LEFT JOIN usca_restaurant_contact_v3_chkng_pk p
ON q.email_address = p.email_address AND q.uuid = p.uuid
WHERE p.email_address IS NULL
AND p.uuid IS NULL
```

You may also want to double check:

- if column types are the same between the email_address and uuid columns in the 2 data extensions
- if accidently any leading/trailing spaces were added during upload

To debug, you may also want to add an additional AND statement to your WHERE clause comparing for a concrete record you expect.

PS: Note there are also solutions out there like [DESelect](https://deselect.io?utm_source=sfse&utm_medium=web&utm_campaign=sf-se-17) that allow you to build and easily test this kind of selections without having to write SQL queries.